# Unable to get sorting and remove duplicates to execute on macro executing on designated worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Attempting to create a macro that will execute by the click of a button on a designated worksheet rather than an active worksheet.  I've been able to get the copy and paste to execute but as the macro works down to sort columns commands, I receive "400" Mircosoft VBA error.  There is no debug error and no line is tagged with an error.  I've tried the same code in Microsoft 2007 and 2016 thinking that it was a version issue but runs the same.  Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub GUIDataExtract()
'Copy and paste data from "LOG PALLET RPT CART-" and then sorts and removes duplicates
'Macro is assigned to button for user to update

Dim wksSource As Worksheet, wksDest As Worksheet
Dim rngSource As Range, rngDest As Range

Set wksSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GUI")
Set wksDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GUI PIVOT")

'Copy First Range of Data
Set rngSource = wksSource.Range("A:A")

'Paste Values First Range of Data
Set rngDest = wksDest.Range("A:A")
rngSource.Copy
rngDest.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

'Sort First Data Range
wksDest.Sort.SortFields.Clear
wksDest.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:B133336"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, 
DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With wksDest.Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:B133336")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

'Remove Duplicates in Data Range
wksDest.Range("$F$1:$K$133336").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 6), Header:=xlYes


End Sub
```

Comment: Is this what you are up against? http://www.repairmsexcel.com/blog/fix-excel-vba-error-400

Comment: In your sort, you are defining ranges A2:B133336 and A1:B133336. I would expect this difference to possibly cause a problem. Try and eliminate it.  Then you want duplicates removed from F1:K133336. There is no evidence in your code snippet that there are any values in that range.

Comment: Where (in which code module) is your code stored?

Comment: One tip that helped me in my VBA endeavors: avoid using `Select`, `Copy`, `Paste` methods etc. You can just do: `rngSource.Value = rngDestination` or even faster use `.Value2`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Variatus.  I've saved the macro in a new module and have eliminated the "400" error.  Thanks!  I do now have a run-time 1004 error relative to the sorting.  "The sort reference is not valid. Make sure that it's within the data you want to sort, and the first Sort By box isn't the same or blank."  I updated the defined ranges per your suggestion but am still getting the same error.  Debug is highlighting 'Apply at the end of sort.

Comment: Danny Papadopulos, thanks for the code suggestion.  I've applied to my application and it has worked, however, my data values begin with leading zeros and are 20 digits long so the values after sorting are truncating.  Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: @MargaretHenderson perhaps try converting the range to text before applying the sort.

Answer (score 0):

I myself resolved to always use [`Sort()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.sort) method of `Range` object

```
With wksSource
    With Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("A:A"))
        wksDest.Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = .Value

        wksDest.Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.Count).Sort Key1:=wksDest.Cells(1, 1), _
                        order1:=xlAscending, _
                        Header:=xlYes, _
                        MatchCase:=False, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
                        SortMethod:=xlPinYin
    End With
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the sorting criteria being more than two columns.

---

wksDest.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("**A2:B133336**"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, 
DataOption:=xlSortNormal

to

wksDest.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("**A2:A133336**"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, 
DataOption:=xlSortNormal